# Want EditText Keyboard with "Enter Key" and without Auto Prediction

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have tried all combination and still not achieved what i want so please help me!

**What I want**

I need **keyboard** without `auto prediction` and with `enter key` for multi purpose

1. **single press** : should go next line
2. **long press** : should show emoji keyboard
   and

here is code

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextWord"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:background="@color/background_walk_through_six"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCharacters"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**What i have tried**

1. > android:inputType="textMultiLine"

or

2. > android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"

With above lines showing `enter key` fulfilled but i can't prevent `auto prediction`

3. > android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"

With above line showing `enter key` with `nextline`[single press] and prevent `auto prediction` means when i add `textVisiblePassword` emoji not showing on long press of `Enter Key`

I have tried programmitically but then it showing `done` button

```
editTextWord.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

I guess you understood now what i need!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programmatically like this:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED);
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS |  InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

As the `inputType` needs multiple values, you could add it to your xml as described there: [How to add many values in android:tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673557/how-to-add-many-values-in-androidtag)